# The problem with CORS headers for the server on Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

Now I am writing a simple server on Go using the standard library net/http. The server is placed in a docker container and placed on google cloud paltform. But when I want to access the server from my third-party React application (which is located on a different server), I always get a CORS error.

Looking for solutions online, I added a library to my code, which is designed to solve the problem of СORS. But adding a library didn’t help. Even after its application, the server does not send me СORS headers. What code do I have now?

```golang
package main

import (
    controller "./controllers"
    "./util"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    //"os"
)

// Entry point
func main() {
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"}, // All origins
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET"}, // Allowing only get, just an example
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Authorization", "Content-Type"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        Debug: true,
    })

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    // Router
    // Live check
    r.HandleFunc("/live", controller.LiveCheck)
    apiRouter := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
    // Medication data
    medicationRouter := apiRouter.PathPrefix("/medication").Subrouter()
    medicationRouter.HandleFunc("", controller.MedicationHeadersList).Methods("GET")
    medicationRouter.HandleFunc("/{id}", controller.MedicationChildrenList).Methods("GET")
    medicationRouter.HandleFunc("/{id}/leafs", controller.MedicationLeafsList).Methods("GET")
    medicationRouter.HandleFunc("/search/", controller.SearchMedicationList).Methods("GET")
    medicationRouter.HandleFunc("/result/{id}", controller.MedicationSearchResult).Methods("GET")

    //r.Use(util.CORS)
    apiRouter.Use(util.VerifyToken)

    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", c.Handler(r)))
}
```

Here is the answer I get from the up-point in the browser console:

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 35.190.37.37:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 22:37:36 GMT
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Via: 1.1 google
```

I also tried to manually set the CORS headers, creating a middleware, but it also did not help.
Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPD** Thank you all for the answers and help. Everything turned out to be much easier. Google did not update my docker container, so all my changes in the code did not give the desired effect. My code, which I gave in the question description, perfectly solves the problem of the CORS. The question can be considered closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. You can use this code in the development environment.

```
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,

        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Authorization", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"},
        // Enable Debugging for testing, consider disabling in production
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "UPDATE", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"},
        Debug:          true,
    })
```

Comment: Did not help( It did not help (The front part still gives the error СORS.

Comment: Yes, the same mistake. The postman does not process CORS, therefore all requests pass through it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

How are you testing this? When a browser must make a cross-origin request that fails pre-flight conditions an `OPTIONS` request gets sent. This `OPTIONS` request contains a header who's value is the HTTP method being used in the cross-origin request.

I stood up your simplified version of your server and here's some example curl commands and results.

The below request works fine, I've set the `Access-Control-Request-Method` to `GET`

```
curl -I -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: test.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" http://localhost:8080/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 02:20:35 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The below request doesn't work without the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header. Our server may have different CORS settings for `GET` and `POST` (etc..), and our server can't communicate that to the client. The client must set the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header so the server knows how to properly respond.

```
curl -I -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: test.com" http://localhost:8080/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 02:31:12 GMT
Content-Length: 436
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here are the headers I send from the front: `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/patients
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Also, what does your Docker configuration look like? What port is your server listening on inside the container? What port gets exposed on the internet? Are you using a proxy like Nginx or Apache inside the container?

Comment: Here is my docekr-compose file `version: '3.3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: 'api'
    build: './api'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - './api:/go/src/app'
    network_mode: host`

Comment: I do not use Apache and  Nginx

Comment: Would you be able to run the same curl commands (adjusting for the appropriate IP address)? Or simulate the OPTIONS/GET request with Postman.

Comment: I ran your command at my place and got the same field as you. But the application reactant still does not receive them.

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting any other headers besides Content-Type and Authorization? Can you share some of the code you use to make the web request to the service?